# Can I apply a mask on an image with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, mask

I have a Rails app where users can upload images. After they upload an image, I need to apply a mask on that image, so parts of it become transparant. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RMagick (a Ruby image manipulation library) allows you to apply clipping path on objects : http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/rvgclip.html

Basically, you'll need to :

- create a clipping path instance
- use the drawing API to draw your mask
- apply the path to your image

A click on the keyhole image" [there](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/rvgclip.html) pops up an example of how to achieve this :

```
require 'rvg/rvg'

hat = Magick::Image.read('images/Flower_Hat.jpg').first
rvg = Magick::RVG.new(hat.columns, hat.rows) do |canvas|
    keyhole = Magick::RVG::ClipPath.new do |path|
        path.circle(60, canvas.width/2, 80)
        path.polygon(canvas.width/2-10, 60, 40, 230, 160, 230, canvas.width/2+10, 60)
    end
    canvas.image(hat, nil, nil, 20, 20).styles(:clip_path=>keyhole)

end

rvg.draw.write('rvg_clippath.gif')
```

**EDIT :**

If you need to apply a transparent background the simplest approach should be to crop your image, then use the `Image#composite!` method to add a trnasparent layer.

Comment: That looks like a great example! I lack knowledge of terminology here I guess. But it seems clipping masks do not support semi transparency. Can I do that too? For example using a mask layer created in photoshop?

Comment: I can't tell for sure if what you say will fix my problem without testing it. I'll give it a go tonight. But it looks like just the right solution!

Comment: Hey I've not used it yet, but thought you may also be interested in https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick (in case RMagick is chewing up too much memory...?)

Comment: This worked great, thanks! Instead of using a gradient fill I was able to load a grayscale image and use that to mask images. Thanks for the mini_magick suggestion, but I the memory isn't that much of a problem in my case, I'm not going to do this very much, only when admins upload an image, once a month or so.

Comment: Glad it worked as expected. To free resources, you can use the `Image#destroy`method.